# JS: using eval on a function while trying to pass an array as parameter, but it throws an error

Tags: javascript, json, object, eval

i want to create a dynamic generated form using javascript, everything works fine, until i try to pass an array as parameter. When i do this, an error happens. Coulr anyone explain what this is?

Heres my code:

```
var loadFrm = function(component) {
    for(nItem in component) {
        var myComponent = "add" + firstToUpper(component[nItem].type);
    var callComponent = myComponent + "(" + component[nItem].opt + ");";
    eval(callComponent);
    }
}

var json = [
    {
        type: "scale",
        opt: {content: [{label: "male", value: "m"}, {label: "female", value: "f"}]}
    }
];

loadFrm(json);
```

**Edit** Here's the error:

```
missing ] after element list
[Break on this error] addScale([object Object]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a debugger to look at the string `callComponent`, you'll probably find it looks something like this:

```
addScale([object Object])
```

...which isn't what you want. That's because you're effectively calling `toString` on your `opt` object, and the default `toString` on objects just looks like that. The `eval` error is because that's invalid syntax.

Generally speaking, any time you think you need to use `eval`, there's almost certainly a better answer. In this case, it looks like you're trying to call a function and pass in `opt`. Assuming these functions are "globals", you can do that like this:

```
var loadFrm = function(component) {
    var nItem, functionName;

    for (nItem = 0; nItem < component.length; ++nItem) {
        functionName = "add" + firstToUpper(component[nItem].type);
        window[functionName](component[nItem].opt);
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eqoko4)

Notes on the above:

1. Don't use `for..in` to loop through arrays unless you [really know what you're doing](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html). `for..in` does not enumerate the indexes of an array, it enumerates the properties of an object.
2. We look up the function by name using `window[functionName]`. This works because "globals" are actually properties of the `window` object, and you can look up properties using a string name for them using bracketed notation.
3. Having gotten the function via `window[functionName]`, we just call it directly, passing in the *object* `opt` rather than a string form of it. I assume `addScale` expects to see an object.
4. I moved all of the `var`s to the top of the function because that's where they really are ([details](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)).
5. If you can, I'd recommend moving `addScale` and the related functions to their own object rather than putting them on `window`. The `window` namespace is already pretty crowded. [Here's the live example](http://jsbin.com/eqoko4/2) modified to not add any symbols to `window` at all, instead putting the `addScale` function on an object called `functions` and using it from there.

---

**Off-topic**: The syntax `var loadFrm = function(component)` creates an anonymous function that it then assigns to a variable. This is used a lot, but unless you're creating different functions based on a condition, e.g.:

```
var f;
if (...) {
    f = function() { ... };
}
else {
    f = function() { ... };
}
```

...it's not actually useful. (If you **are** creating different functions based on a condition like that, then it's not only useful, it's necessary.) I [recommend using named functions](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) whenever possible, because a function with a name helps your tools help you by showing you the function name in error messages, call stacks, etc.

**Off-topic 2**: You have a variable called `json`, but FYI, it's not using [JSON](http://json.org) notation. It's using a combination of JavaScript array and object literal notation, which is a superset of JSON. You'll see a lot of people confused about this, I mention it because you said you're new and so it's worth nipping in the bud. :-) JSON is purely a notation. (A very useful one.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you write a demo code for a possible solution? Im a newbie and i have not a big vision for solutions in JS.

Comment: @Nort: That *is* the code for the solution. I'll throw together a live example, one sec.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
fn = eval(functionName);
fn(objParameter)
```

Comment: Please explain your answer?